# How to change which python GDAL is "connected" to?

Tags: python, gdal, ubuntu

I would like to use GDAL with Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 14.04. I have installed gdal-bin and python-gdal from [UbuntuGIS](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) following their [instructions](https://launchpad.net/+help-soyuz/ppa-sources-list.html). However, importing GDAL (from osgeo import gdal) only works with /usr/bin/python, not the python installation I'm trying to use it with (~/anaconda2/bin/python). How do I point to which python installation to install the GDAL python bindings for?

Comment: I think you can use symlinks to get round this or python virtual environments. But this is probably not really a GIS question.

Comment: Or you could just install gdal into your anaconda environment and have a closed of environment: `conda install gdal`